# Which data model would you use to make 2 dimensional field 100*100 in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

The task is to create in QML field for the game snake 100*100 cells.
data model should be made with Qt C++. What is more suitable `QAbstractListModel` or `QAbstractItemModel` or `QAbstractTableModel`? I am trying to use a `Row` with many `Column` components in QML to create a field 100*100. It looks as a wrong approach. How else is it possible to create field 100*100 in QML and connect it with a model in C++?
I am a fresh guy in QtQuick, googling did not help.

Comment: I don't understand how a _10000_ element table is going to help draw a line moving around a square... Perhaps you should start by telling us what you are trying to do with this table?

Comment: it is snake game. some of cells will randomly turn to wall (red color) and in this field the snake will move.

Comment: Do you **have** to have a C++ model for the cell data?

Comment: @Mitch Yes the only C++ model

Answer (score 0):

Even if `QAbstractTableModel` is able to hold two dimensional data, but there is no simple way to display it in QML (GridView and TableView use only 1D model like ListModel).

I think you should try create your own TilesView and TilesModel, for your own purpose.

> IMHO any advice on this topic is good for some tutorial, and I would love to link to one.

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind here. You could use a `Repeater` and manually the position the items yourself according to their index:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 100 * 10
    height: 100 * 10
    visible: true

    Repeater {
        model: 100 * 100
        Rectangle {
            x: index % 100 * width
            y: Math.floor(index / 100) * height
            width: 10
            height: 10
            border.color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could use `GridView`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 100 * 10
    height: 100 * 10
    visible: true

    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 10
        cellHeight: 10
        model: 100 * 100
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: grid.cellWidth
            height: grid.cellHeight
            border.color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

`Repeater` seems to render slightly quicker.

The more suitable model (though I still think this is not the intended use of models) I'd say would be a simple model like `QAbstractItemModel` or `QAbstractListModel`.